# APPDATA and LOCALAPPDATA environment variables are not set on a profile in Windows 7 Pro 32bit

Tags: windows-7, environment-variables

I am having  problem with a user account on a Windows 7 machine (local install, admin user account)

`APPDATA` and `LOCALAPPDATA` environment are not set. Another user on the same machine, (also a local account, but without admin rights) has the variables set. This started to happen recently, however, I can not figure out if there was something installed on the machine to cause this. This is creating issues with applications that are trying to expand the variables to store local files.

Thank you for the help.

Comment: Probably because it's `APPDATA` and `LOCALAPPDATA`. Although all sane Windows programs are supposed to find the path either by [CIDL](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb762494.aspx) or [KnownFolders](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb776911%28VS.85%29.aspx), and environment variables should not be necessary.

Comment: I've corrected the original question, that was a mistype

Comment: So what is the question? Is there some difficulty re-setting those variables?

Answer (score -1):

Trying backing up the local users important files, delete their user profile and account. Then, recreate the user account and see if the variables are set correctly?

Comment: This would be hard to do since this is the admin user on the system. This is a simle home desktop (not a corporate PC). So user setup is very simple.