# Is there an environment variable for C:\Users\%USERNAME%\AppData\Local\Temp in Windows 7?

Tags: environment-variables

Is there an environment variable that by default points to `C:\Users\%USERNAME%\AppData\Temp` in Windows 7?

Or maybe `C:\Users\%USERNAME%\AppData\local\Temp` for that matter?

Also what are these referred to as?

Comment: Found the answer here: http://superuser.com/questions/234546/appdata-and-localappdata-environment-variables-are-not-set-on-a-profile-in-windo?rq=1

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What are PATH and other environment variables, and how can I set or use them?](http://superuser.com/questions/284342/what-are-path-and-other-environment-variables-and-how-can-i-set-or-use-them)

Comment: I was wrong it's actually `%temp%`

Comment: Not a duplicate. Dupe does not mention `%temp%` or `%tmp%`

Answer (score 12, accepted):

#### Is there an environment variable that by points to

```
C:\Users\%USERNAME%\AppData\Temp
```

No

> Or maybe

```
C:\Users\%USERNAME%\AppData\local\Temp
```

The default value for `%TEMP%` and `%TMP%`  is `C:\Users\{username}\AppData\Local\Temp`

---

#### Windows 7 Environment variables

```
Variable                   Windows Vista/7
%ALLUSERSPROFILE% 
(%PROGRAMDATA%)            C:\ProgramData
%APPDATA%                  C:\Users\{username}\AppData\Roaming
%COMPUTERNAME%             {computername}
%COMMONPROGRAMFILES%       C:\Program Files\Common Files
%COMMONPROGRAMFILES(x86)%  C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files
%COMSPEC%                  C:\Windows\System32\cmd.exe
%HOMEDRIVE%                C:
%HOMEPATH%                 \Users\{username}
%LOCALAPPDATA%             C:\Users\{username}\AppData\Local
%LOGONSERVER%              \\{domain_logon_server}
%PATH%                     C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;{plus program paths}
%PATHEXT%                  .com;.exe;.bat;.cmd;.vbs;.vbe;.js;.jse;.wsf;.wsh;.msc
%PROGRAMFILES%             C:\Program Files
%PROGRAMFILES(X86)%        C:\Program Files (x86) (only in 64-bit version)
%PROMPT%                   Code for current command prompt format. Code is usually $P$G
%SystemDrive%              C:
%SystemRoot%               C:\Windows
%TEMP% and %TMP%           C:\Users\{username}\AppData\Local\Temp
%USERDOMAIN%               {userdomain}
%USERNAME%                 {username}
%USERPROFILE%              C:\Users\{username}
%WINDIR%                   C:\Windows
%PUBLIC%                   C:\Users\Public
%PROGRAMDATA%              C:\ProgramData
%PSModulePath%             %SystemRoot%\system32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\Modules\
```

Source [Windows 7 Environment variables](http://www.binbert.com/blog/2010/09/default-environment-variable-values-of-windows-7-xp/)